Building with static OpenCV libraries
This applies for any UNIX or UNIX-like OS, then Windows, but I have built my C++ (no platform specific code) that uses OpenCV and SDL2 on macOS Sonoma first, according to process of creating .App bundle. In addition, OpenGL is system-available on macOS. I'm using Makefile.
The whole idea is to not have dependency on OpenCV libraries for end-user, that are used on my dev environment, so I want to link against static libraries. Now I'm in anticipation what will happen when I run it on different Mac without OpenCV.
I am copying OpenCV's .a libs to directory Frameworks in the bundle. Using flags for these libraries in target. However they are -I prefix flags, which AFAIK prioritizes dynamic libraries (.dylib) - but the question is - will the linker look for static version of libs (.a) in Frameworks dir? Will following statically link with OpenCV, or is it unavoidable to compile opencv from source with static libraries, for proper build?
Makefile:
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wno-macro-redefined -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_8/include/opencv4 -I/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2 -I/opt/homebrew/include -framework OpenGL
CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.12
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_8/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -framework CoreFoundation -lpng -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -lc++ -lc++abi
OPENCV_LIBS=-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lade -littnotify -lopencv_videoio
SDL_LIBS=-lSDL2 -lpthread
TARGET=SomeProgram
APP_NAME=Some Program.app
SRC=some_program.cpp ResourcePath.cpp

# Default target for quick compilation
all: $(TARGET)

# Target for building the executable for testing
$(TARGET):
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OPENCV_LIBS) $(SDL_LIBS) -o $(TARGET)

# Target for creating the full macOS application bundle
build: clean $(TARGET)
    @echo "Creating app bundle structure..."
    mkdir -p "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/MacOS"
    mkdir -p "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/Resources"
    cp Resources/program.icns "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/Resources/"
    cp Info.plist "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/"
    mv $(TARGET) "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/MacOS/"
    mkdir -p "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/Frameworks"
    cp /opt/homebrew/lib/libSDL2.a "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/Frameworks/"
    cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.9.0_8/lib/*.a "$(APP_NAME)/Contents/Frameworks/"
    @echo "Libraries copied to Frameworks"

# Clean target to clean up build artifacts
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) "$(APP_NAME)"

# Run target for testing if needed
run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)
 

